# Flexbox layout for 5 boxes with big box in the midde

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Flex Design].  I need to create a section wherein the pink box is between a white and blue section.  So I decided that maybe flex is the best way to do this (correct me otherwise).   When seen in mobile I'm expecting the whole pink box width will be 100% and the left and right (white /blue) section will be hidden.

somehow related to codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LNQMML but I need the bigger box in the middle. and the left and right boxes hides on mobile.

Comment: Paulie_D will be upset seeing his pen :p ... so basically you got a ready code and you want us to change it for you?.

Comment: I tried working on the codepen link as I mention but to no avail.   Just new in flex just heard 2 days ago. :)

Comment: you can start by bringing the code to the site and create a snippet here ;) ... by the way, if you heard about it 2 days ago I think you still have a lot to read andto understand, so better take more time on this.

Comment: hope this helps Temani Afif codepen.io/junedc/pen/qyPbPo

Comment: @Kruze  if you are new to CSS please forget about Flex its old and the use of flex box is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appealing to your statement: So I decided that maybe flex is the best way to do this **(correct me otherwise)**

That is really easy to do with modern CSS3 and HTML5 semantic tags.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}
div:nth-child(2){
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.colorp{background-color: #fd79a8;}
.colorw{background-color: white;
}
.colorb{background-color: #0984e3
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
section{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
div:nth-child(2){grid-row: span 2;}
.colorb{display: none;}
.colorw{display: none;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class=" color">
    <section>
      <div id="element1" class=" colorw"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
      <div id="element2" class=" colorp"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
      <div id="element3" class=" colorw"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
      <div id="element4" class=" colorb"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
      <div id="element5" class=" colorb"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

> You can see how it works in this pen [GO TO CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jeanbelmont/pen/GBEzoj/left)

Comment: Perfectly working as expected.  thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help